# How to prevent client to create proxy by add reference from VS IDE

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

suppose i have developed a web service and i want i will ditribute the proxy class to client and then client can add that proxy class to their project to make call of my service but if client some how know the url of my wcf service then he/she will not be to create proxy classes by adding reference from VS IDE.

just tell me what are the area i need to disable in my service when i will design it.

if i remove mex endpoint & httpgeturl = false then will it sufficient ? or anything extra i need to configure ?

i consume one wcf service where company just give me the wsdl & proxy classes. from wsdl i got the service url but when i try to add that service url as add reference from VS IDE then windows auth login diolog comes. so i could not create proxy from VS ide then i just add their proxy related .cs file and call the service. so i like to know how people design their in this way. looking for discussion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help...
Proxy Considerations - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650142.aspx